# Access exchange contacts on device

Tags: ios, exchange-server, abaddressbook

I have an app, that needs to get the user's contacts

providing the user gave access to the contacts

How do i get the exchange contacts ?

I tried the normal method of accessing the phone book, but i want to create my own ui

and in my own ui, only the local contacts appear

this is my code to get the contacts

```
- (void)reloadAddressBook
{
    // Create addressbook data model
    NSMutableArray *contactsTemp = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBooks = [(TKPeoplePickerController*)self.navigationController addressBook];

    CFArrayRef allPeople;
    CFIndex peopleCount;
    if (_group) {
        self.title = _group.name;
        ABRecordRef groupRecord = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(addressBooks, (ABRecordID)_group.recordID);
        allPeople = ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(groupRecord);
        peopleCount = (CFIndex)_group.membersCount;
    } else {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"All Contacts", nil);
        allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBooks);
        peopleCount = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBooks);
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < peopleCount; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactRecord = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);


        if (!contactRecord) continue;

        CFStringRef abName = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        CFStringRef abLastName = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        CFStringRef abFullName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactRecord);
        Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] init];

        NSString *fullNameString;
        NSString *firstString = (__bridge NSString *)abName;
        NSString *lastNameString = (__bridge NSString *)abLastName;

        if ((__bridge id)abFullName != nil) {
            fullNameString = (__bridge NSString *)abFullName;
        } else {
            if ((__bridge id)abLastName != nil)
            {
                fullNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstString, lastNameString];
            }
        }

        if([fullNameString isEqualToString:@"אלי"]){
            LogInfo(@"found eli");
        }

        contact.name = fullNameString;
        contact.recordID = (int)ABRecordGetRecordID(contactRecord);
        contact.rowSelected = NO;
        contact.lastName = (__bridge NSString*)abLastName;
        contact.firstName = (__bridge NSString*)abName;

        ABPropertyID multiProperties[] = {
            kABPersonPhoneProperty,
            kABPersonEmailProperty
        };
        NSInteger multiPropertiesTotal = sizeof(multiProperties) / sizeof(ABPropertyID);
        for (NSInteger j = 0; j < multiPropertiesTotal; j++) {
            ABPropertyID property = multiProperties[j];
            ABMultiValueRef valuesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRecord, property);
            NSInteger valuesCount = 0;
            if (valuesRef != nil) valuesCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(valuesRef);

            if (valuesCount == 0) {
                CFRelease(valuesRef);
                continue;
            }

            for (NSInteger k = 0; k < valuesCount; k++) {
                CFStringRef value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(valuesRef, k);
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: {// Phone number
                        contact.tel = [(__bridge NSString*)value telephoneWithReformat];
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: {// Email
                        contact.email = (__bridge NSString*)value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                CFRelease(value);
            }
            CFRelease(valuesRef);
            if(contact.tel.length == 0){
                continue;
            }
        }

        [contactsTemp addObject:contact];

        if (abName) CFRelease(abName);
        if (abLastName) CFRelease(abLastName);
        if (abFullName) CFRelease(abFullName);
    }

    if (allPeople) CFRelease(allPeople);

    // Sort data
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *theCollation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];


    SEL sorter = ABPersonGetSortOrdering() == kABPersonSortByFirstName ? NSSelectorFromString(@"sorterFirstName") : NSSelectorFromString(@"sorterLastName");

    for (TKContact *contact in contactsTemp) {
        NSInteger sect = [theCollation sectionForObject:contact
                                collationStringSelector:sorter];
        contact.sectionNumber = sect;
    }

    NSInteger highSection = [[theCollation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *sectionArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:highSection];
    for (int i=0; i<=highSection; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
        [sectionArrays addObject:sectionArray];
    }

    for (TKContact *contact in contactsTemp) {
        [(NSMutableArray *)[sectionArrays objectAtIndex:contact.sectionNumber] addObject:contact];
    }

    for (NSMutableArray *sectionArray in sectionArrays) {

            NSArray *sortedSection = [theCollation sortedArrayFromArray:sectionArray collationStringSelector:sorter];
            [_listContent addObject:sortedSection];


    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```